# Fibres, rammification points and continuity

Tags: general-topology

Trying to understand the relation between the following: given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with all fibres either empty or of size 3, what can be said about the continuity of such a function? I started off trying to think in reverse about an induced map (not the inverse of $f$) $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ from the image of $f$ to the set of fibres as a multi-valued function which has 'branch' or 'rammification' points (of discontinuity) where the fibre size is 1, then thinking about what this says about the continuity $f$. But now I'm thinking is it simply something to do with how the connectedness of the fibres of size 3 affects the continuity of $f$? A steer would be appreciated.

Comment: Show that a continuous function from the reals to itself cannot have this property of empty or three-point fibres using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: I'm still uncertain, by the IVT if I take (preimage $\{x,y,z\}=f^{-1}(y)$) for $f:f^{-1}(y) \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$ so any of $x,y,z$ will give me $f(y)$ back, but does this mean that I don't return a value that is 'strictly' between $f(y)$ because every value I can obtain is $f(y)$ itself (thus in effect using the contrapositive of the IVT to show why $f$ cannot be continuous)? What about an ascending sinusoidal or sawtooth function such that there are three occurrences of $f(y)$, each for a different $X$ so all fibres are three-point? Thanks

Comment: Two notes:
1. This is an assignment question from http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/MATH3961/r/14ass2.pdf

2. You're on the right track.